# Why are a polygon's vertices jumbled after importing KML into MySQL?

Tags: polygon, kml, intersection, mysql, invalid-data

This is original KML :

> `<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>104.700355,-3.056064 104.632127,-3.103623 104.608924,-3.103169 104.570166,-3.102411 104.5588,-3.102189 104.548864,-3.101994 104.541136,-3.101843 104.539013,-3.096237 104.532201,-3.093863 104.529785,-3.094935 104.527678,-3.09587 104.523719,-3.097496 104.51814,-3.098398 104.515191,-3.094125 104.513645,-3.091885 104.509867,-3.089893 104.506745,-3.091407 104.504648,-3.092423 104.501949,-3.092783 104.50105,-3.09206 104.501052,-3.087899 104.501145,-3.084665 104.501235,-3.081569 104.501144,-3.078221 104.501058,-3.075057 104.501071,-3.070607 104.500982,-3.067082 104.500888,-3.063309 104.504724,-3.061848 104.506625,-3.060745 104.508358,-3.059739 104.509017,-3.057638 104.509732,-3.055358 104.510934,-3.053721 104.512236,-3.051951 104.513852,-3.048543 104.516622,-3.047081 104.518616,-3.046029 104.520796,-3.044975 104.522249,-3.043272 104.524268,-3.041244 104.525964,-3.039784 104.526759,-3.038864 104.529417,-3.03524 104.53179,-3.034574 104.533498,-3.034098 104.536629,-3.033908 104.539476,-3.034196 104.541942,-3.034483 104.545185,-3.034802 104.548135,-3.036879 104.550593,-3.038264 104.553149,-3.039649 104.556197,-3.041232 104.558949,-3.042815 104.561113,-3.043014 104.564358,-3.044004 104.566816,-3.04351 104.570357,-3.04193 104.57295,-3.040828 104.575472,-3.039757 104.578225,-3.040846 104.578026,-3.044899 104.577533,-3.049051 104.579401,-3.05093 104.583053,-3.05176 104.587661,-3.052317 104.593266,-3.052122 104.599375,-3.052082 104.602331,-3.051026 104.605286,-3.04997 104.607189,-3.04997 104.607895,-3.046784 104.608393,-3.044533 104.608594,-3.041915 104.608295,-3.038794 104.609199,-3.03094 104.610102,-3.027114 104.610704,-3.0251 104.61371,-3.021275 104.615625,-3.019821 104.618218,-3.017853 104.622124,-3.01866 104.627211,-3.021898 104.63029,-3.023859 104.634942,-3.02682 104.638805,-3.029536 104.643254,-3.032663 104.647961,-3.035484 104.650865,-3.037399 104.654753,-3.039698 104.656407,-3.043291 104.657303,-3.045239 104.660602,-3.047907 104.662506,-3.049447 104.663797,-3.046664 104.664951,-3.044177 104.666693,-3.04042 104.668224,-3.039292 104.672103,-3.037446 104.673736,-3.036831 104.676492,-3.035704 104.679348,-3.038167 104.683021,-3.04104 104.68598,-3.042888 104.687813,-3.044215 104.690509,-3.046166 104.694448,-3.049441 104.697912,-3.052961 104.700355,-3.056064</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>`

When i preview with FusionTable layer: the layer looks good,
[image: image can display normally]

Then i edit file structure (i try input into Mysql), like this:

```
<?php mysql_query(" INSERT INTO tblplacemarkpoint (tblplacemark_id, tblplacemarkpoint_longitude, tblplacemarkpoint_lattitude, tblplacemarkpointis_active) VALUES ('1', '104.700355', '-3.056064', 'T')");mysql_query(" INSERT INTO tblplacemarkpoint (tblplacemark_id, tblplacemarkpoint_longitude, tblplacemarkpoint_lattitude, tblplacemarkpointis_active) VALUES ('1', ' 104.632127', '-3.103623', 'T')"); ... ?>
```

[image]

I don't understand the problem. Can someone explain to me what happened?

Comment: Did you transform it in any way. This can happen when vertices get out of order, somehow, or inner rings (which it doesn't look like you have any of), get combined into the outer ring.

Comment: I try to input coordinates into Mysql, then i generate the polygon from lattitude, longitude saved in the database

Comment: How did you input the coordinates? You need to explain all your steps, for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have one polygon, you have many.

It looks like the xy coords from all polygons are just dumped into one large list to make a single polygon. Hence the polygon boundary is jumping around creating bad topology.

As the above commenters say, your question is poor. But, taking a guess: if you only want one polygon merge your data together prior to adding it to mysql. A tool like [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/) would be ideal.